# Building C++ code with components in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, include, include-path

I have a C++ project which can be compiled using cmake command with no error.

The problem is that I can't find the `BaseCode.cpp.o` and `BaseCode.cpp.o.d` in the build folder, also, when I run make command in the build folder, I get the following error:

```
myCode/BaseCode.h: No such file or directory
```

The C++ project has the current structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── myComponent
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── src
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── library
│       │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │   └── myCode
│       │       ├── BaseCode.cpp
│       │       └── BaseCode.h
│       └── test
│           └── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp
```

The `main.cpp` files looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <myCode/BaseCode.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

The first `CMakeLists.txt` file in ***root folder*** (same as in `main.cpp`) is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(myTestProject)

# Set the components to build
set(components myComponent)

# Include subdirectories for each component
foreach(component ${components})
    add_subdirectory(${component})
endforeach()

# Set the output directory for the executable
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# Add the executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` file in ***library folder*** is like this:

```
set( HEADERS 
   myCode/BaseCode.h
  ) 

set( SOURCES 
  myCode/BaseCode.cpp
  )

add_library( myCode SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} )
set_property( TARGET myCode PROPERTY VERSION ${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION} )
target_link_libraries(myCode PRIVATE ${PROJECT_NAME})

install( DIRECTORY myCode/
        DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}
        COMPONENT devel
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h" )

install( TARGETS myCode DESTINATION lib COMPONENT runtime )
```

The `CMakelists` in ***myComponent folder*** is:

```
add_subdirectory(src)
```

The `CMakeLists` in ***src directory*** is similar:

```
add_subdirectory(library)
```

Comment: You show only content of the root `CMakeLists.txt` and `myComponent/library/CMakeLists.txt` one. But what is content of `myComponent/CMakeLists.txt`? Also, the error message about not finding `myCode/BaseCode.h` should be accompanied with much more information. E.g. it should include the path to the file which is currently compiling. Please, include **complete error message** into the question post.

Comment: The CMakeLists are simply add_subdirectory,  as for the error it is the only one, it points the line number in the main.cpp (line 2) and then after that there is compilation terminated

Comment: I replicated your project and its structure on my end, I did get the error you mentioned, so I changed `#include <myCode/BaseCode.h>` to `#include "myComponent/src/library/myCode/BaseCode.h"` and the error went away, I got another error but I think it's because I don't have  everything that you have, see if this works

Comment: Great that you managed to replicate it, I have mentionned that I could not find the BaseCode.cpp.o and BaseCode.cpp.o.d files in the build folder "build/", normally they should be located in: build/myComponent/src/library/CMakeFiles/MyCode.dir/MyCode/

Comment: I can find `BaseCode.cpp.o` in that exact location on my end, could you share your BaseCode.cpp and .h files? I think i need to replicate exactly what you have

Comment: I have a single class with one void method, if you manage to make the import using the library-notation include "#include <...>" instead of "#include ''full_path_to_header" then the issue is solved

Comment: For construction `#include <myCode/BaseCode.h>` being worked, the directory `<root>/myComponent/src/library` should be among directories to be included by the compiler. You specify none include directories, so it doesn't work. In CMake include directories are specified with `include_directories` or `target_include_directories` command.

Comment: I tried what @Tsyvarev mentioned, adding `include_directories(myComponent/src/library)` to your main CMakelists file (in your root folder) gets rid of the error, `#include <myCode/BaseCode.h>` works fine.

Comment: Please write a detailed answer, I'll try to reproduce it, once working then problem solved

Comment: did you mean to do `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE myCode)` instead of `target_link_libraries(myCode PRIVATE ${PROJECT_NAME})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by [Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev)

> For construction `#include <myCode/BaseCode.h>` being worked, the
> directory `<root>/myComponent/src/library` should be among directories
> to be included by the compiler.
>
> You specify none include directories,so it doesn't work.
>
> In CMake include directories are specified `include_directories` or `target_include_directories` command.

And from [CMake include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) documentation:

> ### include_directories
>
> ***Add include directories to the build.***
>
> ```
> include_directories([AFTER|BEFORE] [SYSTEM] dir1 [dir2 ...])
> ```
>
> Add the given directories to those the compiler uses to search for
> include files. Relative paths are interpreted as relative to the
> current source directory.

To fix the error you're getting, you need to add the following to your main `CMakelists` in your root folder:

```
include_directories(myComponent/src/library)
```

This is the `CMakeLists` file after adding that command:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Structure)

# Set the components to build
set(components myComponent)

# Include subdirectories for each component
foreach(component ${components})
    add_subdirectory(${component})
endforeach()

# Set the output directory for the executable
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

include_directories(myComponent/src/library)

# Add the executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

That should do the trick (it did on my end).

I got an additional error so I will mention it here just in case.

When I tried to run it, I got the following error:

> cannot find -lmyTestProject: No such file or directory

And to fix it, I deleted the command below from the `CmakeLists` file in your `library` folder:

```
target_link_libraries(myCode PRIVATE ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

It ran fine and displayed

```
Hello World!
```